# LazyLoadingEnabled setting doesn't seem to work in EF 5

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm using EF Model first with POCO entities and with custom DbContexts. My problem is that setting `LazyLoadingEnabled=false` does not affect anything, navigation properties are still loaded.
Below is my example simplified.

The entity Program. A program can be part of other programs:

```
namespace Domain.Entities
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Program
    {
        public Program()
        {
            this.Programs = new HashSet<Program>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ProgramId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Program> Programs { get; set; }
        public virtual Program OwnerProgram { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The DbContext:

```
namespace Infrastructure.Model
{
    public class ProgramContext : DbContext
    {
        public ProgramContext()
            : base("name=MyContainer")
        {
            Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        }

        public DbSet<Program> Programs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is how I use it:

```
private ProgramContext _dbContext = new ProgramContext();

// GET api/program
public IEnumerable<Program> GetPrograms()
{
    List<Program> list = _dbContext.Programs.ToList();
    return list;
}
```

With the above sample, EF still loads the Programs and OwnerProgram properties of the Program class. I have tried removing the virtual keywords, disabling the proxy creation and also verified that `LazyLoadingEnabled=false` on the Model itself.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The effect you are seeing is called **relationship fixup**.

Actually the navigation properties are *not* loaded explicitly. The query `_dbContext.Programs.ToList()` only loads the whole `Programs` table from the database. This is just a simple SQL query (like `SELECT * FROM ProgramsTable`) without any `WHERE` clause and without any `JOIN` to related rows.

Also no lazy loading happens here (it really can't if you disable it and if you disable even dynamic proxies) when you access the `program.Programs` and `program.OwnerProgram` navigation properties.

The navigation properties get populated when the result from your query is materialized because your query (that loads *all* programs) will have loaded all programs that the navigation properties can refer to. EF detects that those related entities are already in memory and put them into the navigation properties automatically.

You can verify this if you don't load *all* programs but only, for example, a single one:

```
Program program  = _dbContext.Programs.FirstOrDefault();
```

Now, `program.Programs` and `program.OwnerProgram` will be `null` - unless the loaded `program` is part of its own `program.OwnerProgram` collection or is its own `OwnerProgram`.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I'm seeing. Is there any way I can make EF not load navigvation properties unless I'm using .Include() ?

Comment: @gixen: As said, it is not really "loading". Relationship fixup just puts the entities into the navigation collections and references that are already loaded anyway. So, there is no query overhead. If you want to modify entities after loading you need change tracking and you can't disable this behaviour. Without change tracking in read-only situations you can try `_dbContext.Programs.AsNoTracking().ToList()`. But I'm not sure if it will help in this case.

Comment: What I am getting out of this answer is there is no way to load an entire object graph in EF without an open context to lazy load navigation properties. OR .Include("NavigationProtperyName") can be explicitly called to load Navigation properties, but it is required on each query.

Answer (score 2):

> "EF still loads the Programs and OwnerProgram properties of the Program
>   class"

This is the correct behavior, but instead of loading the navigation properties lazily, it loads them eagerly.

This means that the database queries required to retrieve the navigation property values are executed immediately when the `Program` entity is retrieved and the navigation properties are populated.

When `LazyLoadingEnabled` is set to `true` these queries aren't triggered until you attempt to access the navigation properties. This also applies to when you're hovering your mouse over navigation properties and the debugger is attached, which may lead you to think that the entities aren't being lazily loaded when in fact they are - the debugger is accessing the navigation property, so Entity Framework loads it.

You can run a SQL profiler such as [this one](http://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/) to see exactly when queries are being triggered as you debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

> With the above sample, EF still loads the Programs and OwnerProgram
>   properties of the Program class. I have tried removing the virtual
>   keywords, disabling the proxy creation and also verified that
>   LazyLoadingEnabled=false on the Model itself.
>
> Am I missing something?

You need to remove default constructor that initializes these properties.