# List contains one object why?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, collections

I have a problem where an object containing a list property holds 1 item, which it shouldn't (it should be empty).

The Station class contains a list of edges (List Edges). 
The Edge class have a EndStation, which is of the type Station.

The problem is, after returning the IQueryable from GetEdgesByStartStation(), the EndStation on each Edge contains a list of edges (List Edges) which is not empty (as it should).
The item in the list are the Station (edge.EndStation) it self. I've tried to illustrate it with comments in the code below

```
public IQueryable<Edge> GetEdgesByStartStation(Station station)
{
    var edges = db.Edges.Where(x => x.StartStationId.Equals(station.ID));
    foreach (var edge in edges)
    {
        edge.EndStation = db.Stations.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID.Equals(edge.EndStationId)); 
        //Here the edge.EndStation.Edges would contain 1 item, edge.EndStation 
        //eg. edge.EndStation = "Miami", edge.EndStation.Edges = { "Miami" }
    }

    return edges;
}
```

What I wanted this code to do, was get all the edges for the Station passed to the method. For each edge, connect a EndStation with an empty list of edges.

Station class:

```
public partial class Station
{
    public Station()
    {
        this.Reservations = new List<Reservation>();
        this.StationMaintenances = new List<StationMaintenance>();
    }

    [DataMember]
    //[JsonConverter(typeof(Int32))] 
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    //[JsonConverter(typeof(Int32))] 
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public decimal StationLat { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public decimal StationLong { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool IsOperational { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual BatteryStorage BatteryStorages { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual List<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual List<StationMaintenance> StationMaintenances { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual List<Edge> Edges { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual StationType StationType { get; set; }
}
```

Edge class:

```
public partial class Edge
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int StartStationId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int EndStationId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual Station EndStation { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public decimal Distance { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public decimal Time { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

}
```

How can this be?

Comment: You need to give more information. First it would be best if you add a fully compilable and executable code example in the question. If you cannot do that (for instance, you might require a database), at least provide all the code *in* the question. By that I mean that you should add in the classes from the github project, and prune them down to what is relevant to this question. Next, you say "it shouldn't". The problem is, what should it contain? Zero? Many?

Comment: Why shouldn't it hold an item? This bug, if any, is probably unrelated to the posted code.

Comment: Or it maybe in the database relationship.

Comment: If I'm reading this right - it's what EF does (automatically filling in) - it's the other side of the relation - each EndStation by being added to the list of stations - automatically has the 'one Edge' in the opposite navigation property. Is that what's bothering you ?

Comment: @NSGaga Yes, if I understand your question correctly, you're right - that is was bothering me. The List<Edge> (list of edges) on edge.EndStation are not empty when I return the IQueryable<Edge> from the method.

Comment: That's what's called `relationship fixup`. `Station EndStation` and `List<Edge> Edges` are on the opposite sides of the same relationship. When materializing object from the Db (`edge.EndStation = ...`) the EF figures out that the opposite side is your 'edge' which it already has in the memory - so it does the fixup and fills that in, whether you like it or not. - you should take a look at this answer here for some details [LazyLoadingEnabled setting doesn't seem to work in EF 5](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16375162/417747)

Comment: @NSGaga CLosing is a temporary state. As soon as all the relevant code is in the question, it should be re-opened.  Linking to external sites that hold your code is something we don't want to encourage. Once the code in those links changes, or the link dies, this question becomes useless for future Googlers.  We're not just here to provide help, we're here to be a Q & A site -- and that means having permanence in the questions.  If you want to help out the OP by editing the question into shape, go for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's called `relationship fixup`.

`Station EndStation` and `List<Edge> Edges` are on the opposite sides of the same relationship.
When materializing object from the Db (the `edge.EndStation = ...` line) the EF figures out that the opposite side is your 'edge' which it already has in the memory - so it does the fixup and fills that in, whether you like it or not.

You should take a look at this answer here for some details [LazyLoadingEnabled setting doesn't seem to work in EF 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16357141/lazyloadingenabled-setting-doesnt-seem-to-work-in-ef-5/16375162#16375162)

As @Slauma mentioned, I don't think there is a way of disabling that - I'm guessing it's just logical to have both filled (if no extra loading from Db is required).

Comment: Okay, so my only option to remove the Edge from the List is to manually overwrite or clear the list for objects?

Comment: @NSGaga: You could delete your comment under the question now. Especially George Stocker will be happy :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180325/help-us-figure-out-a-way-to-handle-the-explosion-of-comments-on-stack-overflow

Comment: @KLIM8D I don't think you should try to manually clear it (and that'd effectively affect your other side as well, which you don't want). That list is a logical consequence of how your relationships are set up. Maybe you actually need and want your relationship a bit differently, like having a 'default' or main station - and edges list separately - you should think about that I guess

Comment: @KLIM8D: This can be dangerous depending on what you intend to do with the loaded data. If you use the data readonly (you should use `AsNoTracking()` then by the way for better performance), i.e. dispose the context after you have loaded them, you can clear the list safely. But if you want to apply some changes in the same context you have loaded the data in and then call `SaveChanges` later clearing the list or removing an item from the list will be detected as a relationship change and this change will be written to the database.

Comment: @NSGaga I can't seem to find any other way doing this relationship, it is used for pathfinding (A star algorithm) and therefore I need the edges connected between 2 vertices (Stations), but I will think about it thanks.

Comment: @Slauma I'm only using the loaded data read only, so I think I will stick with clearing the list and using AsNoTracking(). Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Yes you shouldn't save them - but also be careful not to implicitly attach or invoke save. Personally this looks to me like you don't want the two to be the part of the same relationship (and if it sounds like a duck...). So, in your case your edges for the algorithm could be just for that, and not related to EndStation - and make EndStation has its own 'counterpart' list navigation (which doesn't have to be specified e.g. `WithMany()` being empty) - that way you don't have to worry, it will be separated. I mean that's in theory, you'd have to see if it makes sense or may introduce problems.

Comment: @NSGaga I'm not exactly sure what you mean. I need Edge to contain an Station object, to where the edge is going to. I might be possible with the way you describe. My edges are equal to the lines in this gif from the A-Star article at Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:AstarExample.gif
 I think it's fixed. I've added AsNoTracking() to the line in my for-each loop, and this seems to return an empty list :)

Comment: that's great side-effect then:), interesting (@Slauma was spot on as always, this answer is half his). I was theoretical, not specific (you could've also made a notmapped readonly list property etc.), anyway, doesn't matter now - this is better

Comment: @KLIM8D: It works because you are running separate queries, loading the edges first, then n times loading an end station in the loop. Normally, I'd say, why not loading everything in a single query: `db.Edges.Include(e => e.EndStation).Where...`? But your problem with the populated edges list of the endstations would return then (even with `AsNoTracking`) :)