# Entity Framework POCO Eager Loading children

Tags: entity-framework, entity, poco, eager-loading

This is my POCO entities scenario:

`Manufacturer` (1) has `Cars` (*)

One `Car` entity has a navigation property to a `Manufacturer` entity.

One `Manufacturer` entity has a navigation property to a Cars collection

I need to query all `Cars` of a specified color, with their respective `Manufacturer`, so my EF query would be:

```
Context.Cars.Where(i=>i.Color=='White').Include("Manufacturer").ToList();
```

This is what I get:
A list of `Cars`, with the `Manufacturer` correctly populated

The problem is that the `Manufacturer` entity brings it navigation property `Cars` populated as well:

`Cars.FirstOrDefault().Manutefacturer.Cars` is full of cars....

How can I get rid of this undesirable behavior?

Thanks a lot.

**UPDATE #1:**
I do have the following properties set:

```
this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that the Manufacturer entity brings it navigation
>   property Cars populated as well:
>   `Cars.FirstOrDefault().Manufacturer.Cars` is full of cars....

Yes, but only of white cars...

It's not an additional join in the database query that asks for the `Cars` collection of each loaded manufacturer. But just the cars that you loaded in your query - the white cars - are added to the collections of their respective manufacturer. The Entity Framework context does this when the loaded data get materialized to entities. It's called *relationship fixup* and you can't disable it. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16375162/270591) was a similar question and answer recently.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that this behavior is expected, yet I am not convinced that we have to live with this. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might have lazy loading enabled, which will automatically load navigation properties from the database the first time they're accessed.

You can disable it for your entire `DbSet` in the constructor:

```
public MyContext() : base()
{
  this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
}
```

Then only the navigation properties you load manually with `Include()` will be present.

That said, if you're accessing the `Cars` property, you *want* it populated, don't you?  And if you're not accessing it, then the lazy loading won't happen in the first place.

Comment: Nice try, but I do have the property LazyLoadingEnabled = false.... And no, I just accessed the Cars property to check if it was being populated... I dont want this behavior... but thanks.