# SQL LINQ query keeps looping through two tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, linq

I am trying to call a linq query in asp.net 5. However, my query results in an infinite loop of data between two tables.

```
Logs (logs_historical)
 meterID (FK)
 log_data
 -----
Meters
 meter_uid (PK)
```

My goal is to have multiple logs related to one meter.

```
 Relationships
 Foreign key Base Table = logs
 Foreign key Column = meterID
 Primary Base Table = meters
 Primary Key Colum = meterID
```

This is my linq query

```
 records = dbContext.logs.Where(e =>(e.timestamp.Value.Month == inputDate.Month)).ToList() ;
```

1) This screenshot shows the table information and (foreign key table)
[image: Debugger Showing table information of]
When I look into the foreign key table information, it also has the logs.
Going into the logs will show the same table from picture (1)

2)
[image]
I'm sure this was asked before, but I do not know what this problem is called. I am new to databases. Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a quick fix, you can probably use        dbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
just before your query. You can disable it globally as well.

What happens is Entity Framework will eagerly load all related entities. If you have entities that go several levels deep, or that reference each other, well, as you have experienced, it will continue to follow those relationships. Disabling lazy loading will prevent this. Please note that you will have to explicitly declare anything you want included via the .include() function.

The other option is to redesign your database so that this isn't the case, but sometimes that just isn't feasible. I don't really know the intricate workings of your project, so I am speculating here.

EDIT:

I forgot to add, if you go into the model browser and explore the models that were created for you by Entity Framework, you will find those relationships that are causing the issue. If you are using code first, you can easily fix this. If you are using database first, you are somewhat at the mercy of how EF interprets relationships.

Comment: I think this lazyloading function is what I want. However, when I implement the function, nothing is changed. The entity still queries all of the navigation tables. I am using database first =\ ..

Comment: Thank you for your advice on lazyLoading... I did some more research and came across this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16357141/lazyloadingenabled-setting-doesnt-seem-to-work-in-ef-5 The real solution is to add both lazyLoadingEnabled=  false AND dbContext.logs.AsNoTracking().Where(...)

Comment: Cool! Glad I could point you in the right direction. I wasn't thinking about tracking.